# Using CircleCI workflows for iOS apps

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, circleci, fastlane

I'm currently getting into using CircleCI for an iOS app with fastlane. I see there is a feature called workflows, which I'd quite like to use. However the CircleCI documentation somehow suggests this is a CircleCI 2.0 feature and builds on OS X / macOS seem to be CircleCI 1.0 only. Again, however, the docs here: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/sample-config say:

> The CircleCI 2.0 configuration introduces a new key for version: 2. This new key enables you to try 2.0 while continuing to build on 1.0.

This again suggests: you're all set using workflows and 2.0 features while building on 1.0. Right?

But how? This question does not get answered in the docs and I was wondering whether anyone was able to get it working. Anyone?

Comment: For anyone reading this: I got a reply from CircleCI. This is an unclear passage in the Docs and they actually mean: "you can still use 1.0 on some projects while using 2.0 on others." In other words: no iOS builds with 2.0 right now. However it seems they're working hard on getting 2.0 ready for iOS :)

Answer (score 1):

The [official fastlane Circle guide](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#circle-integration) is based on Circle 1.0, make sure to have a config file that looks like the following

```
machine:
  xcode:
    version: "7.3"
dependencies:
  override:
    - bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle --jobs=4 --retry=3 --without development
  cache_directories:
    - vendor/bundle
test:
  override:
    - bundle exec fastlane test
```

Comment: Hey Felix :)
Yes I saw that documentation and I started building with that config. However that does not answer the question on how to make workflows work :(

Answer (score 0):

As of today (August 12th, 2017):

- CircleCI 2.0 does not support OS X/macOS
- Workflows is a feature of CircleCI 2.0 only

The paragraph likely could be improved though. I've opened an Issue in our public [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/circleci/circleci-docs/issues/1429).

- Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI